# how to see the body of __add__() method in python. whenever we see + operator, __add__() is called

Tags: python, operators, addition

can we see the inside/body of the "+" operator.
whenever we encounter "+" operator, in actual, `a.__add__(b)` happens.
but can we see this `__add__()`?

Comment: There are different bodies depending on the operand types. There is no general way to see them. For the built-in types and types of standard library they are in the source code of Python as C or Python code.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the code line by line using pdb (though reading directly from the source code would be easier)

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> a,b = Fraction(3,10), Fraction(6,10)
>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.runcall(a.__add__, b)
```

And this will start an interactive shell where you can execute the code line by line. You just need to use "n":

```
> c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\fractions.py(375)forward()
-> if isinstance(b, (int, Fraction)):
(Pdb) n
> c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\fractions.py(376)forward()
-> return monomorphic_operator(a, b)
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\fractions.py(376)forward()->Fraction(9, 10)
-> return monomorphic_operator(a, b)
(Pdb) n
Fraction(9, 10)
```

(As someone else pointed out, you can also use `inspect` module)

Answer (score 1):

To view module source code of the non-C modules/functions/classes, use [getsource](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) from `inspect`.

```py
import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(a.__add__)
```

But there is a simpler solution, you can use your IDE or text editor, which supports **Go to Definition** feaute.

For **VSCode** it's `F12` key, by default, with python extension.
For **Pycharm** it's `ctrl+B` shortcut.

To view built-in sources, look at official [CPython github](https://github.com/python/cpython)